# Как правильно создавать лог "лайкования" пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Я хочу воплотить одну вещь. Вот допустим у меня есть много новостей. К ним можно ставить лайки. Каждый пользователь, или IP может поставить один лайк. Вот как это записывать в БД?

Есть идея создать таблицу. В ней колонки ip, user, news - IP, с которого поставили лайк, юзер, который поставил лайк, если залогинен и ID новости, к которой поставлен лайк, соответственно. Не знаю, верно так теоретически или нет, но посчитав.. если к примеру будет 100 новостей, и у каждой по 100 лайков, то это уже 10000 строк в таблице БД. Наверняка ведь проверка поставил пользователь лайк или нет, будет занимать не мало времени.

В общем подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать?

Comment: твой вариант единственный который приходит на ум.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотреть надо не спозиции как хранить и справится ли БД, а с позиции какие данные будут нужны.

Например. Возьмем новости. Т.е. со временем новости стареют и посетитель к старым новостям не возвращается, информация о лайках нужна только другим пользователям.

1. С точки зрения пользователя, лайкнувшего данную новость, если он опять ее откроет - эту информацию достаточно хранить в куках, со временем эта информация не так уж важна, ну лайнет он ее через неделю еще раз, ну и пусть.
2. С точки зрения других пользователей, которым информация о том, кто именно лайкнул эту новость, совершенно не нужна. Достаточно хранить количество лайков для новости. Одна новость - одна запись.

Другой пример. Статьи, которые ищутся поиском в любой момент и то, что было в прошлом веке тоже важно и интересно, особенно для закрытых комьюнити. Тут понятно таблица (статья, юзер), вопрос остается с индексами.

1. С точки зрения пользователя, нужно знать какие статьи он лайкнул, чтоб не допускать повторных лайков (накрутки и т.д.). Нужен индекс по юзеру.
2. С точки зрения других пользователей, опять же в основном нужна информация о количестве лайков. А о том, кто именно лайкал - дополнительная информация, которая выдается по дополнительному запросу. Для статьи опять же хранить аггрегацию лайков не помешает, чтоб не делать `select count`. Ну и индекс в таблице (статья, юзер) по статье.

Answer (score 1):

вариант навскидку. 
таблица, 2 столбца:
ид юзера |
ид новости - хранит все ИДшники лайкнутых новостей

или же:
ид новости |
ид юзеров, которые ее лайкнули

Comment: Ага, один миллион лайков и пиши пропало. При каждом запросе будет обход всей таблицы.

Comment: миллион... миллиард :) че это за новости такие там должны быть? в высоконагруженых системах используются технологии типа hadoop.. хотя для простых сайтов и обычные приемы подойдут..

Comment: @Gorets но уточнить про индексы всё равно следовало бы.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица с двумя столбцами:

```
+-------------------+
| news_id | user_id |
+-------------------+
```

На оба столбца по индексу. Для неавторизованных нужно запрещать лайкать статьи.